# I can't get rails plugin wicked_pdf to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I wanted to create PDFs for my rails application using wkhtml2pdf and wicked_pdf.
I downloaded and extracted wkhtml2pdf beta 4 and placed it in /usr/local/bin/wkhtml2pdf
I tried running it on a web site and it gave a nice result.

In my rails application (2.3.4) I installed wicked_pdf:

> script/plugin install git://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf.git
>   script/generate wicked_pdf

Everything seemed to be ok.
inside script/console I run the following - (with the following output)

```
wp = WickedPdf.new
```

=># WickedPdf:0xb62f2c70 @exe_path="/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf"

```
HTML_DOCUMENT = "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"
```

=> "`<html><body>Hello World</body></html>"`

```
pdf = wp.pdf_from_string HTML_DOCUMENT
```

=> "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf - - -q"

=> "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

of course this isn't good. According to the test the result of my last command should start with "%pdf-1.4"

Any idea what I can do?

Comment: does it not require the string to be valid xhtml?

Comment: of course it does :), I had to escape the html tags in the question... editted the question now

Comment: Good Qvestion - Using the rails console like this helped me debug my configuration problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same problem. Removed the `-q` option from the `wicked_pdf.rb` file on line 19 and then was able to get the proper string on the console.

```
=> "%PDF-1.4\n1 0 obj\n<<\n/Title ...
```

This also seems to have solved other problems. The PDF still didn't render correctly when using it from the web site - embedded font issue - on to the next issue now.

Hopefully this will work for you.